# Xamarin form : How to save data from push notification when app is closed

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am saving my notification in database when i receive, its working fine when app is open, but when i close app from here as shown in image below it doesnt save in database

[image: close app from here]
i am really stuck here because it doesnt save in database when my app is close. Here is my code for save in database when i recieve notification.

```
 protected override void OnStart()
        {
 CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += async (s, p) =>
            {

                    bool isread = false;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
                    if (p.Data["open_page"].ToString() == "NewAppointment")
                    {
                        Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                        {

                            await notification.InsertNotificationAppointmentDate(notify, p.Data["title"].ToString(), p.Data["body"].ToString(), isread, p.Data["open_page"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(p.Data["appointmentDate"]));

                        });

                    }
 };

}
```

i just need to know where i have to put this code to run and save data in database when app is totally close.

Comment: did you try saving data while OnMessageReceived in the push notification broadcast receiver?

Comment: broadcast reciever? how to do that?

Comment: How you are receiving the push notification?

Comment: from firebase through code

Comment: like this code 
 WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                var objNotification = new
                {
                    to = user_token,
                    data = new
                    {
                        title = titlee,

Comment: this is sending the request... how you are receiving the notification at the app side? Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181068/discussion-between-hashimks-and-waqas-waqas).